# Trying to scale a webm video to 50% of its resolution using FFMPEG but keep getting an error (video has transparency btw)

Tags: ffmpeg, webm

I'm trying to scale down a webm video with transparency using this line of commands (based off of an answer in this stackoverflow question @ [How to keep transparency when scale webm file with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840816/how-to-keep-transparency-when-scale-webm-file-with-ffmpeg)):

`ffmpeg -c:v libvpx -i in.webm -c:v libvpx -vf scale=400:416 -auto-alt-ref 0 out.webm`

but I keep getting errors (for example):

```
[libvpx @ 00000128eb6123c0] Invalid sync code 310042.
[libvpx @ 00000128eb6123c0] Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF
```

Full log (I've removed a ton of the same exact message with "..."'s):

```
ffmpeg version 2021-02-02-git-2367affc2c-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 64.100 / 56. 64.100
  libavcodec     58.120.100 / 58.120.100
  libavformat    58. 65.101 / 58. 65.101
  libavdevice    58. 11.103 / 58. 11.103
  libavfilter     7.101.100 /  7.101.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
[libvpx @ 00000128eb6123c0] v1.9.0-146-gebb5ffc1d
[libvpx @ 00000128eb6123c0] Invalid sync code 310042.
[libvpx @ 00000128eb6123c0] Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
[libvpx @ 00000128eb6123c0] Invalid sync code 007a49.
[libvpx @ 00000128eb6123c0] Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
[libvpx @ 00000128eb6123c0] Invalid sync code 01f096.
[libvpx @ 00000128eb6123c0] Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
...
...
...
[libvpx @ 00000128eb6123c0] Invalid sync code 01f096.
[libvpx @ 00000128eb6123c0] Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
[libvpx @ 00000128eb6123c0] Invalid sync code 01f096.
[libvpx @ 00000128eb6123c0] Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
[libvpx @ 00000128eb6123c0] Invalid sync code 01f096.
[libvpx @ 00000128eb6123c0] Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
[libvpx @ 00000128eb6123c0] Invalid sync code 01f096.
[matroska,webm @ 00000128eb60f040] decoding for stream 0 failed
[matroska,webm @ 00000128eb60f040] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: vp8 (libvpx), none(progressive), 800x832): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'in.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libwebm-0.2.1.0
    creation_time   : 2017-12-02T12:06:12.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2592 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, none(progressive), 800x832, SAR 1:1 DAR 25:26, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
[libvpx @ 00000128eb612a40] v1.9.0-146-gebb5ffc1d
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp8 (libvpx) -> vp8 (libvpx))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libvpx @ 00000128eb612a40] Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[libvpx @ 00000128eb612a40] Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[libvpx @ 00000128eb612a40] Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
...
...
...
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[NULL @ 00000128eb6123c0] Invalid sync code 01f096.
[libvpx @ 00000128eb612a40] Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[NULL @ 00000128eb6123c0] Invalid sync code 01f096.
[libvpx @ 00000128eb612a40] Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[NULL @ 00000128eb6123c0] Invalid sync code 009c96.
[libvpx @ 00000128eb612a40] Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF
Error marking filters as finished
Conversion failed!
```

Log of `ffmpeg -i input.webm`:

```
ffmpeg version 2021-02-02-git-2367affc2c-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 64.100 / 56. 64.100
  libavcodec     58.120.100 / 58.120.100
  libavformat    58. 65.101 / 58. 65.101
  libavdevice    58. 11.103 / 58. 11.103
  libavfilter     7.101.100 /  7.101.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libwebm-0.2.1.0
    creation_time   : 2017-12-02T12:06:12.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2592 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv), 800x832, SAR 1:1 DAR 25:26, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: the video I'm trying to scale down 50% with transparency is https://cdn.streamelements.com/uploads/49ae16d7-6407-4322-859b-74819cba0cf1.webm

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: I've added the log. I've removed a lot of the similar messages that were outputted with "..."'s

Comment: Share full log of `ffmpeg -i input.webm`

Comment: Added log. Output wasn't specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i in.webm -c:v libvpx -vf scale=400:416 -auto-alt-ref 0 out.webm
```

The input video is VP9, whereas `libvpx` decoder is for VP8.

Do the same thing for the output if you want a VP9 stream.

Comment: thanks! it worked! how do i add a hue filter to change the hue to say more blue?

Comment: Add it after the scale filter, separated by a comma.

Comment: ```ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i in.webm -c:v libvpx -vf scale=400:416, hue=h=45:s=1 -auto-alt-ref 0 out.webm``` gave an error ```Unable to find a suitable output format for 'hue=h=45:s=1'
hue=h=45:s=1: Invalid argument```

Comment: No space after the comma.

Comment: I get an error: ` Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input`

Comment: nvm, it works if I remove the `-vp9` bit

Comment: This helped me out big time today, thank you!